# Does anyone who has experience with loading GA4 log data to Supabase database?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4, supabase, supabase-database

I work as a growth marketer in a startup.
For various growth marketing activities, I'm using raw data by linking GA4 and Big Query.

By the way, my company is trying to build a user's DB called Service Log into a database provided by a place called Supabase.

I expect that I need to do a lot of joining between DB and DB to analyze users, so I want to load ga4 log data into one place(Supabase).

So, I am looking for a way to load GA4's log data into Supabase, not GCP(Google Cloud Platform).

If anyone has had similar concerns or solved them, please help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the query -- I'm not too familiar with Google Analytics(GA) 4. However, it seems like you can [export reports as CSV](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9317657?hl=en) which you can then import into Supabase. I'm unsure if that is the log data that you are looking for though.

In general, you can import data in CSV format into a Supabase table by doing:

`New Table > Import Data as CSV`

Hope this helps in some way

[image: How to import data from CSV]